# Increase scrollbar contrast

Tags: themes, gtk, accessibility

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to change the color of the scroll bar?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/103246/how-to-change-the-color-of-the-scroll-bar)

I've been following several bugs since Lucid was released:

- [scrollbars are really hard to see with the ambiance/radiance themes](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/light-themes/+bug/563474)
- [[ambiance, radiance] slider on scrollbar haves zero contrast](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/light-themes/+bug/537048)

The short of is, I have difficulty distinguishing the scrollbar grabby bit from the trough it lives in. Several "fixes" have been committed with absolutely no change to the contrast in this area (despite bold claims by their authors :@).

**How can I increase the contrast of brightness or color between the scrollbar trough and bar, without adding theme specific hacks, or constrain those changes to only the themes I have difficulty with?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry to revive this topic, but I've posted an answer [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/114018/46882) that might be helpful for anyone suffering from this problem...

Answer (score 1):

You could install "gnome colour chooser" from the 'software centre' and this would allow you to tweak any colour you like.  A detailed answer, explaining how to tweak scrollbar colors using "gnome colour chooser" is available [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/299865/322753).