# How to reset my gtk theme's defaults?

Tags: themes, configuration, gtk

I was trying to change the scrollbar's color's or contrast to make it more easily noticeable but after using  [this question's answers](https://askubuntu.com/questions/103246/how-to-change-the-color-of-the-scroll-bar/108731) I got this effect on my windows

[image]

this is my [/usr/share/themes/Ambiance/gtk-2.0/gtkrc](http://pastebin.ca/2177818)

How can I revert to the default theme ( I am using Ambience theme right now)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since re installing the themes is by far the easier thing to do:

- `sudo apt-get install --reinstall light-themes`