# How to get around low contrast scrollbars?

Tags: unity, overlay-scrollbars

The problem is I'm using Unity, the theme is Ubuntu Mono Dark, and I'm using non overlay scrollbars so I'm having a hard time actually seeing the scrollbar.

This bug has been plaguing me since at least 2011 and it doesn't look like anybody has looked at this. See here for an actual bug report: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubuntu-themes/+bug/721786

Answer (score 1):

I solved the non existent scrollbar in Google Chrome by installing the extension ["Clearlook Scrollbar Theme"](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/clearlook-scrollbar-theme/ppfdcmehpgiojcjgpclmfnbnpdmcmbgo). Since Google Chrome is my go to browser this solves the problem for the web. I managed to patch things up with Gnome Terminal and Gedit by editing some system files but I don't really count that as solving the problem since these fixes will get wiped out by updates.

For my other gnome apps I used [the advice given here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/103246/how-to-change-the-color-of-the-scroll-bar) to install the addon gnome-color-chooser. I also edited the file "/usr/share/themes/Ambiance/gtk-3.0/gtk-widgets.css" around line 1500, but I don't really think this solves the problem.

Comment: it would be a better answer if you can described exactly what system files and what changes you made.  Thanks.

Comment: OK. As much as it pains me to do so, I will do that.

Comment: what exactly did you change at around line 1500?  FYI - if you copy the Ambiance folder to ~/.themes (then flip between radiance & ambiance in the themes window to activate this local copy) you wont ever have to worry about updates upsetting your changes.

Comment: I changed a couple of things so I'd really need the original file to get a precise diff. I never considered using a local copy of the css to be honest since in my experience updates tend to break things remorselessly.