# Strange orange line in terminal

Tags: command-line, 16.04, unity

My freshly installed Ubuntu terminal has a strange orange line to the right. It seems that it is related to the focus, that is, when the window is out of focus the line turns grey (but it doesn't disappear). It has been many years since I don't install Ubuntu so I don't know if this is a bug or a feature. In any case, is there any way to remove that line?

PS1: it also happens in fullscreen

PS2: in fact it seems to me that the text is very close to the left edge, maybe it is related to that?

[image]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It's not a bug, that's a scrollbar, if you wrote a long command on terminal. You'll see the actual form of the scrollbar. The scrollbar length will be shorter every time you enter command that will generate long text, says `apt-get update` (if you have many PPAs).

[image]

I doubt you want to remove scrollbar, but there is way to disable/removing them on terminal. Its quite easy:

1. Open terminal.
2. Go to Edit > Profile Preferences.
3. Navigate to Scrolling tab.
4. Uncheck "Show Scrollbar".

[image]

Now the scrollbar is gone.

Comment: I feel very silly know. Can you change the color of the scroll bar, let's say to white?

Comment: This [answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/324968/253251) explain how to modify system-wide scrollbar color.

Comment: Don't feel so silly - it seems a really ugly scrollbar, indeed.

Answer (score 5):

That "orange line" is the *scrollbar*. You will notice that as the text displayed in the terminal grows longer the orange part grows shorter. When the orange part is shorter than the window height you can drag it up and down to show parts of the scrollbuffer.

The ratio between the orange part and the height of the terminal gives you a clue about how much text is available in the scollback buffer; the position of the orange part corresponds to the position in the scrollback buffer which is currently displayed in the window.